# How to add custom css/js to just one page in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I made a separate html file with custom css and js files. I want to integrate it into a wordpress site. I can copy and paste the body part of the html, however I don't know how to add css and js files properly. If I modify header.php, it will add these files to all pages and I don't want that. What is the solution?

Comment: something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89494/how-to-enqueue-the-style-using-wp-enqueue-style/89495

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you will add the page from the `WordPress` back end, using `Pages->Add new` from the menu, you have to give a title and using that title (also possible using slug and id) you can check `is_page('page title here')` and then can add `JavaScript` and `css` files, like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addcssAndScripts');
function addcssAndScripts()
{
    if ( is_page('page-title') )
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'your-style' );
    }
}
```

paste this code in your `functions.php` and check [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for better understanding of these functions and usage, also [is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) and [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) if needed.