# Where to put JS and CSS files (that are for one page) in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I have a HTML code for one page in my wordpress site and for the style of that there's two JS and one CSS files, I tried locating them in JS and CSS folder in the editor section of my theme, but it doesn't work.

Can I add those code inside the  tag of HTML? If not, where should I put them?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this question read this link.

[How to add custom css/js to just one page in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639723/how-to-add-custom-css-js-to-just-one-page-in-wordpress)
or

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addcssAndScripts');
function addcssAndScripts()
{
    if ( is_page('page-title') )
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'your-style' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked that link, what is the 'page-title'? is it the url of that page or just the name of the page?
and in the 'your_script/style' is should write the name of js and css files, right?

Comment: It would be appreciated, if you can help me with this more:)